# date format and phone number format

Tags: user, user-record

I have a few user who complained that the date format and phone number format are the US ones.
This is creating issues as the number of digits are not the same for phone numbers, and people may misunderstand dates.

How do we update these?

Answer (score 1):

Date and phone format come from Locale.

So, you need to update locale (API Name: `LocaleSidKey`) for those users.

Refer [Supported Locale](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5)